# php echo string with variable for a link

Tags: php

I know I am going to get a lot of downvotes for this but, I really can't seem to get this working:

I am trying to make the link simply go to (say variable is blahblah) /listen?v=blahblah
However, I end getting /listen?v="blahblah" or errors.

Here is the snippets of the php lines I have tried:

```
echo "<a href='/listen?v=$escapedString'>";

echo "<a href='/listen?v=" . $escapedString . "'>";
```

And I have tried separating the parts onto individual lines etc etc, I honestly don't see why it's doing this.

Comment: `$escapedString` already has the quotes, how are you defining it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your both lines are correct, so the quotes must be inside the content of the variable, you can trim them like this:

```
$escapedString = trim($escapedString, '"');
```

or just do it for the link:

```
echo "<a href='/listen?v=" . trim($escapedString, '"') . "'>";
```

Comment: Oh damn thanks that worked. Sorry It completly slipped my mind to backtrack to see what the variable actually was.

Answer (score 0):

You need your file extension. For example, if it's a PHP file...

```
echo "<a href='/listen.php?v=$escapedString'>";
```

Comment: The strange thing is I'm still recieving the variable in quotes?